# Scan files recursive and non recursive using Pathlib python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to scan files in given folder/directory, if recursive is True recursivly scan directory else only files can yield. I am implemented below code, I am getting None

```
import re
import uuid
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Generator, Tuple, Union, Optional
import time


def scan_files(dir_path: Union[str, Path], filter_regex: Optional[str] = None, recursive: bool = True) -> Generator[Tuple[str, Path], None, None]:
    """
    Get list of files in the specified directory.
    """
    path = Path(dir_path)
    for item in path.iterdir():
        if not item.is_symlink():
            if recursive and item.is_dir():
                yield from scan_files(item, filter_regex=filter_regex)
            elif filter_regex is None or re.match(filter_regex, item.name, re.IGNORECASE):
                yield str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_URL, str(item))), item


while True:
    print("=" * 100)
    for x, y in scan_files(dir_path="/tmp/in/106/", recursive=True):
        print(x, y)
    print("=" * 100)
    time.sleep(4)
```

Actual output: No files are yield from scan_files

test input files

create directory

```
 /tmp/in/106/nested

 add below files 
 /tmp/in/106/1.mov
 /tmp/in/106/2.mov
 /tmp/in/106/nested/1.mov
 /tmp/in/106/nested/2.mov
```

expected output:

```
   if recursive:  all files with full path 

   if non recursive: /tmp/in/106/1.mov and /tmp/in/106/2.mov
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Path.glob` with either a recursive or non-recursive pattern:

```py
import re


def get_files(path, recursive=False):
    pattern = '*.mov' if not recursive else '**/*.mov'

    for file in Path(path).glob(pattern):
        if item.is_symlink():
            continue
        
        yield file


# Then filter using a regex
def scan_files(directory, recursive=False, regex=None):
    paths = get_files(directory, recursive=recursive)

    if regex is None:
        it = paths
    else:
        r = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)
        it = (p for p in paths if r.search(p.name))
    
    for p in it:
        item = p.absolute()
        yield str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_URL, str(item))), item
```

### Edit

Use a catch-all regex to accomplish this more neatly and in one function:

```py
def scan_files(directory, recursive=False, regex=None):
    pattern = '**/*.mov' if recursive else '*.mov'
    regex = regex if regex is not None else '.'

    r = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)
    
    for p in Path(directory).glob(pattern):
        if not r.search(p.name):
            continue
        elif p.is_symlink():
            continue

        item = p.absolute()
        yield str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_URL, str(item))), item
```